# Define a number on the drawn card

Tags: javascript

I'm making a blackjack game with js.
It's still in development, but when the dealer or player draws an A(I'm doing dealer processing here), I want to decide the 'Ace'  as 1 or 11 in favor of it.
The dealer must keep drawing cards until the value is 17.
If the dealer exceeds 21, it will burst.
I want to get an advantageous value when A is drawn under this condition
I want a vanilla js answer if you possible

Comment: Assume all the aces are 11. Iterate over the aces, converting each to 1 until the sum becomes <= 21. Note that the dealer doesn't have a choice about how they play; they follow house rules for how to treat an ace with regards to whether they hit or stay.

Comment: Not sure if this an exercise or not, but the dealer's count does not start at 0, it starts at the face value of the dealer's first card placed face up on the table during the initial draw. The dealer's first ace (which _may_ be the face up card on the table) count's as 11 if the total doesn't go over 21, or 1 if it does. All aces drawn by  the dealer after their first ace count as 1. So the answer is 19 if the dealer dealt themselves an 8 first, later followed by an ace. Are you trying to change the rules?

Comment: Why would you consider [1, 1, 1, 1, 8] to give 12 as advantgeous value? I don't understand what is wrong with 19?

Comment: My explanation was bad.
At the beginning of the game, the dealer has been given two cards in advance, one of which is on the back. When Deaker draw A and align your hand, I want to make it 17 or more and less than 21 as much as possible. Using 1 or 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would advise not to mix I/O with game logic. Your function should focus only on working with the cards, not with `document`. Let the function *return* whatever info is needed from it. The main program code should then deal with output.

For your example, the output should be 19, as the dealer will stop after getting 8+11, as that sum is at least 17. It may be more interesting to look at another example:

```
[4, 7, 6, 5, 1]
```

Here the sum should be first 11+5, but then when the 6 comes in, it should correct to 1+5+6, taking the 7 and then stop: 1+5+6+7=19

The following function will do that, using an extra boolean variable which will be true when an ace was used as value 11:

```js
function drawDealerCard(cards) {
    let dealerTotal = 0;
    let hasEleven = false;
    while (cards.length > 0 && dealerTotal < 17) {
        let card = cards.pop();
        if (card == 1 && !hasEleven) {
            hasEleven = true;
            card = 11;
        }
        dealerTotal += card;
        if (dealerTotal > 21 && hasEleven) {
            hasEleven = false;
            dealerTotal -= 10;
        }
    }
    return dealerTotal;
}

const deck = [4, 7, 6, 5, 1];
console.log(drawDealerCard(deck));
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
In the case of [1,8,10,2], it should be 21, but why is it 20?

Comment: Because you wrote that *"The dealer must keep drawing cards until the value is 17"*. So when reaching 20, the dealer will not draw that last card (which is a 1).

Comment: indeed.What is -10 for?

Comment: It is the difference between 11 and 1.